# How can I categorize all columns in a data at once? (Make all values become High, Medium, Low)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I am trying to convert all values in my dataset into categorical values, I want all numerical values to be categorized into low, average or high depends on their quantile values.

So if the value is lower than 25% of the series, it will be converted as "Low"

I have tried to use assign then applied a function that I provide:

```
def turn_into_categorical(row):
    quantile_level = [.25, .5, .75]
    for r in row:
        cut = refugees_T_F_V_P_full_data.r.quantile(quantile_level)
        if r >= cut[.75]:
            return "High"
        elif r >= cut[.25] and r < cut[0.75]:
            return "Average"
        else:
            return "Low"

refugees_T_F_V_P_full_data.apply(turn_into_categorical, axis = 1)
```

However, the code doesn't work well. I have also tried it via iterrows but I wonder if there's a faster way to do it?

Here is the data that I wanted to convert, all number excluding Year and Month should be categorized into Low, Medium, High, depending on their quantile value.

```
    Year  Month  Central Equatoria  Eastern Equatoria  Gogrial  Jonglei
0   2014     10                6.0                1.0      0.0      3.0   
1   2014     11                4.0                3.0      0.0     12.0   
2   2014     12                3.0                5.0      0.0     11.0   
3   2015      1                7.0                2.0      0.0      4.0   
4   2015      2                5.0                5.0      0.0     10.0   
5   2015      3                7.0                5.0      0.0      8.0   
6   2015      4                4.0                1.0      0.0      6.0   
7   2015      5                5.0                0.0      0.0      7.0   
8   2015      6                4.0                1.0      0.0      6.0   
9   2015      7               15.0                2.0      0.0      9.0   
10  2015      8               10.0                7.0      0.0      9.0   
11  2015      9               12.0                0.0      0.0      8.0   
12  2015     10               12.0                0.0      0.0      5.0   
13  2015     11                8.0                5.0      0.0     10.0   
14  2015     12                5.0                7.0      0.0      3.0
```

Expected Outcome: (Example)

```
    Year  Month  Central Equatoria  Eastern Equatoria  Gogrial  Jonglei
0   2014     10                High             Medium      Low      Medium  
1   2014     11                Low              Medium      Low     high
```

Comment: As a comment, this is a well written question with an interesting problem - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up using the oldest fashion:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
name_list = list(df)

for name in name_list:
    if name != 'Year' and name != 'Month':
        new_row = []
        quantiles = df[name].quantile([.25, .5, .75])
        row_list = df[name].tolist()
        for i, value in enumerate(row_list):
            if value < quantiles[.25]:
                new_row.append("Low")
            elif value < quantiles[.75] and value >= quantiles[.25]:
                new_row.append("Average")
            else:
                new_row.append("High")
        series = pd.Series(new_row)
        new_df[name] = series.values

new_df.head()
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want [`pd.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.qcut.html), which does precisely that. From the docs:

> Quantile-based discretization function

So you could [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) `pd.qcut` along the columns of the dataframe starting from `Central Equatoria` onwards, specifying the quantiles you want to use to bin the Series with `q = [0, 0.25, 0.75, 1.0]`

```
df.loc[:,'Central Equatoria':].apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, q=[0, 0.25, 0.75, 1.0], 
                                    labels =['low','medium','high']) 
                                    if not x.nunique() == 1 else 'low'))
```

**Output**

```
       Central Equatoria Eastern Equatoria Gogrial Jonglei
0            medium              low     low     low
1               low           medium     low    high
2               low           medium     low    high
3            medium           medium     low     low
4            medium           medium     low    high
5            medium           medium     low  medium
6               low              low     low  medium
7            medium              low     low  medium
8               low              low     low  medium
9              high           medium     low  medium
10             high             high     low  medium
11             high              low     low  medium
12             high              low     low     low
13           medium           medium     low    high
14           medium             high     low     low
```

Comment: Better solution than mine :).. basically this combines `quantile` & `cut` Pandas methods.

Comment: Yes it bins directly using the quantile information. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried to implement yours and @jpp 's code, but it seems like the pd.qcut function always return the error `ValueError: ("Bin edges must be unique: array([0., 0., 2., 7.]).\nYou can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg", 'occurred at index Northern Bahr el Ghazal')`

Comment: I tried to search for a solution for this from here [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15069) and added an argument `duplicates='drop'`, but it stills return `ValueError: ('Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges', 'occurred at index Northern Bahr el Ghazal')`

Comment: full code is here `refugees_T_F_V_P_full_data.iloc[:,2:].apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x,duplicates='drop', q = [0, 0.25, 0.75, 1.0], labels = ['low','medium','high']) if not x.nunique() == 1 else 'low')`

Comment: The dataset for this question can be find here on GitHub: [link](https://github.com/hbshih/17-18-Project/blob/master/refugees_T_F_V_P_full_data.csv)

Comment: Unfortunately can't check now, will give it a look later

Comment: `Bin edges must be unique: array([0., 0., 2., 7.])` is clear. You've got `0` in there twice somehow. How can you bin values between 0 and 0? There's a quick hack to fix this but you'd be better understanding how you got duplicate values in your bins.

Answer (score 1):

One idea using `pd.DataFrame.quantile` with `pd.Series.cut`:

```
cats = ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']
quantiles = df.iloc[:, 2:].quantile([0, 0.25, 0.75, 1.0])

for col in df.iloc[:, 2:]:
    bin_edges = quantiles[col]
    # special case situations where all values are equal
    if bin_edges.nunique() == 1:
        df[col] = 'Low'
    else:
        df[col] = pd.cut(df[col], bins=bin_edges, labels=cats, include_lowest=True)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

    Year  Month CentralEquatoria EasternEquatoria Gogrial Jonglei
0   2014     10           Medium              Low     Low     Low
1   2014     11              Low           Medium     Low    High
2   2014     12              Low           Medium     Low    High
3   2015      1           Medium           Medium     Low     Low
4   2015      2           Medium           Medium     Low    High
5   2015      3           Medium           Medium     Low  Medium
6   2015      4              Low              Low     Low  Medium
7   2015      5           Medium              Low     Low  Medium
8   2015      6              Low              Low     Low  Medium
9   2015      7             High           Medium     Low  Medium
10  2015      8             High             High     Low  Medium
11  2015      9             High              Low     Low  Medium
12  2015     10             High              Low     Low     Low
13  2015     11           Medium           Medium     Low    High
14  2015     12           Medium             High     Low     Low
```

Comment: If the OP is willing to take int labels not strings, we could vectorize this I think. I'm just trying to finalise an idea

Comment: @roganjosh, `pd.cut` I believe is fully vectorised, the "string" series at the end are in fact efficient categoricals, i.e. backed by integer arrays.

Comment: Ah poop, I saw the `for` loop and read it the wrong way! I was going for `np.digitize`. You're correct AFAIK.

Comment: I have tried the code but it return the same error that got me when I tried @yatu's code `ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([ 0.,  0.,  5., 26.]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg
`

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.cut()` and `df.apply()`:

```
df.iloc[:,2:]=df.iloc[:,2:].apply(lambda x:pd.cut(x, 3, labels=['Low','Med','High']), axis=1)

    Year    Month   Central_Equatoria   Eastern_Equatoria   Gogrial Jonglei
0   2014    10      High    Low         Low                 Med
1   2014    11      Low     Low         Low                 High
2   2014    12      Low     Med         Low                 High
3   2015    1       High    Low         Low                 Med
4   2015    2       Med     Med         Low                 High
5   2015    3       High    Med         Low                 High
```